# Cannot read property 'createIcon' of undefined using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, leaflet

I'm trying to show some markers that are on my database in a leaflet map. However, everytime I run the projec I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createIcon' of undefined":

[image]

I have an array of 20 items with  the attributes latitude and longitude. (They all have the same coordinates, because I was testing something, but at least should appear one marker).

[image]

Here is the code that it's creating each marker:

```
$.get("/api/IgnicoesAPI", function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    //identificação do tipo de marcador que deve aparecer de acordo com o estado da ignição
    var ignicao;

    if (item.estado == "aceite") {
      ignicao = L.icon({
        iconUrl: "/icons/aceite.png",
        iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
      });
    } else {
      if (item.estado == "emAvaliacao") {
        ignicao = L.icon({
          iconUrl: "/icons/emAvaliacao.png",
          iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
        });
      } else {
        if (item.estado == "concluido") {
          ignicao = L.icon({
            iconUrl: "/icons/concluido.png",
            iconSize: [35, 35], // size of the icon
          });
        } else {
          if (item.estado == "recusado") {
            //ignicao.removeFrom(map);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //colocar um marcador no mapa de acordo com a latitude e longitude fornecidas
    var marker = new L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude], {
      icon: ignicao,
    })

      .on("click", function onClick(e) {
        var id = item.id;

        //assim que um marcador for clicado é mostrado o popup das ignições
        modal.style.display = "block";

        //indicação do marcador que foi clicado
        clickedmarker = e.target;
        console.log(clickedmarker);

        //vai buscar toda a informação correspondente ao id fornecido
        getData(id, clickedmarker);

        //Actividade dos botões presentes no popup das ignições
        $(document).on("click", "#aceite", function () {
          //se o estado for aceite, o botão respetivo estará desativado
          if (item.estado == "aceite") {
            document.getElementById("aceite").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("recusado").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("concluido").disabled = false;
          }
          //se for clicado passará ao icon correspondente
          else {
            clickedmarker.setIcon(accepted);
            //fecha o modal das avaliação da ignição
            modal.style.display = "none";
            //atualiza a base de dados com o novo estado
            atualizaBD(id, "aceite");
          }
        });

        $(document).on("click", "#concluido", function () {
          //se o estado for concluido, o botão respetivo estará desativado
          if (item.estado == "concluido") {
            document.getElementById("concluido").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("aceite").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("recusado").disabled = false;
          }
          //se for clicado passará ao icon correspondente
          else {
            clickedmarker.setIcon(conclued);
            //fecha o modal das avaliação da ignição
            modal.style.display = "none";
            //atualiza a base de dados com o novo estado
            atualizaBD(id, "concluido");
          }
        });

        $(document).on("click", "#recusado", function () {
          //se o estado for recusado, o marcador será removido do mapa
          //clickedmarker.removeFrom(map);
          //clickedmarker = null;
          modal.style.display = "none";
          //atualiza a base de dados com o novo estado
          atualizaBD(id, "recusado");
        });
      })
      .addTo(map);

    //adiciona marador ao mapa
    $("#json map").append(marker);
  });
});
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Chances are that `ignicao` is `undefined` when you're creating a marker. Debug that to be sure. Chance the logic so that the marker is not created when there's no icon for it (or have a fallback icon).

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue, you should modify the `handColorIcon` function to return the `L.Icon` object that it creates. For example, you could have added a return statement at the end of the function:

```
handColorIcon(color){
  return new L.Icon({
    iconUrl:
        `https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-${color}.png`,
    shadowUrl:
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize: [41, 41],
  });
}

this.handColorIcon('green');
```